# Calling Red5 APIs from oflaDemo

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flex4, red5

I have been looking, as much as possible, at the source code for Red5's oflaDemo client. I have been trying to figure out how the client accesses the functions provided in the server- side code.

I have looked at the oflaDemo flash file using Adobe Flash, and do not see any script code in it at all. I don't see anything that starts the playback of any of the movies selected. I don't see anything that invokes any of the services in DemoService for getting the list of available movies in the streams directory. I do not know how the server- side functions are invoked at all.

Could someone point me to examples of how to invoke the server- side functions in a Red5 application? Where is the code that does this in the oflaDemo application? Is there any client- side documentation (other than the non- contextual Javadocs) that can tell how to do this from the client side? Are there any tutorials on how to use client- side functions to invoke server- side functionality???

Comment: I would be helpful if you could post a link to the demo application.

Comment: ??? I do not understand your question, Christophe. I am talking about the oflaDemo, which is a standard demo included with the Red5 download. The Red5 demo page points to a standard place to get the flash source (http://red5.googlecode.com/svn/flash/trunk/). That is pretty much all we have to work with...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is in the Flash file on the first frames of the "Code" and "Buttons Code" layers. Right-click the frames that have a little "a" on them and choose "Actions" from the popup menu.

Comment: Thanks. I found the code. I will need to translate it to AS3, but at least I can study it. Again: thanks.